# How to implement two onlicklisteners for two groups of buttons in two layouts?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to set two button onclicklisteners for two different columns of buttons (set in two layouts, A layout and B layout, with buttons from A1-A8 and B1-B8) in order for the next screnario to work: I want buttons from their own layouts not to have any action between them (for example when I click A2 and then A7 nothing to happen, and after A7 if I click A3 again nothing to happen, and still if I click A8....and so ON) but when I click for example A1 and B7 after that, I have some code that compares text of buttons and that part is working fine. But i'm strugling with the first part, the part where buttons from the same layout should tako no action when clicked. I was adviced to use two onlicklisteners (now I use only one for all buttons) but I didn't find the way to finish that. I settext to buttons randomly from imported prepopulated sqlite database. Here's my code so far:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.spojnice);

        a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA1);
        a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA2);
        a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA3);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB3);


        nextQuestion();


        }

public void nextQuestion() {




        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{ 

            mDbHelper.open();

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsA = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();
            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsB = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();

            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(2), "1"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(3), "1"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(4), "2"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(5), "2"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(6), "3"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(7), "3"));

            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);


            question.setText(c.getString(1));

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0).label);
            a1.setTag(labelsA.get(0).tag);
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a1.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a1.setEnabled(true);
            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0).label);
            b1.setTag(labelsB.get(0).tag);
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b1.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b1.setEnabled(true);
            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1).label);
            a2.setTag(labelsA.get(1).tag);
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a2.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a2.setEnabled(true);
            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1).label);
            b2.setTag(labelsB.get(1).tag);
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b2.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            a3.setText(labelsA.get(2).label);
            a3.setTag(labelsA.get(2).tag);
            a3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a3.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a3.setEnabled(true);
            b3.setText(labelsB.get(2).label);
            b3.setTag(labelsB.get(2).tag);
            b3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b3.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b3.setEnabled(true);

        }
```

I placed this line of code in my xml for every button, tagging it for left and right layout, maybe it will help. I didn't find how to make it helpful:

```
android:tag="L"
android:tag="R"
```

For comparing purposes this code works fine, but it also compares buttons from the same layout, and I can't have that. How to implement two onclicklisteners to manage this issue of mine?

EDIT:

I tried with an array but it did not work.

```
private static final int[] idArrayA = {R.id.bA1, R.id.bA2, R.id.bA3, R.id.bA4, R.id.bA5, R.id.bA6, R.id.bA7, R.id.bA8};
        private static final int[] idArrayB = {R.id.bB1, R.id.bB2, R.id.bB3, R.id.bB4, R.id.bB5, R.id.bB6, R.id.bB7, R.id.bB8};

final OnClickListener clickListenerA = new OnClickListener(){



        public void onClick(View v) {
               if (Arrays.asList(idArrayA).contains(v.getId())) {
                    return;   
               }else{
//do some code here if pressed buttons are not from the same array

}

        }

       };
```

---

This is what I've done so far, and I'm not getting anywhere. Can someone help me out with some actual code, to wrap this thing, cause this keeps me in place. I have tried with two onclicklisteners and it's not working at all, it actually working less well than the first code I started with.

I placed this in my activity scope:

```
private Button buttonClicked;
```

And two onClickListeners:

```
final OnClickListener clickListenerA = new OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View v) {

            Button button = (Button) v;
            button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

            if (buttonClicked == null) {
                    // first button is clicked
                    buttonClicked = button;
                } else {
                    // second button is clicked
                    if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {

                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        counter = counter + 5;
                        score.setText("Poeni: " + counter);
                    }
                }

        }
       };

       final OnClickListener clickListenerB = new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button button = (Button) v;
            button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

            if (buttonClicked == null) {
                // first button is clicked
                buttonClicked = button;
            } else {
                // second button is clicked
                if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {

                    buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                    buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    counter = counter + 5;
                    score.setText("Poeni: " + counter);
                    }
            }

        }

};
```

Comment: First of all, I suggest you use an array since the variable names only differ by a number.

Comment: Second of all, try reducing your example code to the fewest number of buttons that are required to ask your question. (Probably 2 or 4.)

Comment: OK, edited. Can you give me an example how would you handle my problem with an array?

Comment: I still think you have too many buttons. You only need a1, a2, b1, and b2.

Comment: "I tried with an array but it did not work." What does "it did not work" mean? Please provide more detail. Also, keep it simple. Even with arrays, you should use only 4 buttons to start. Once you get those working add all the buttons you need.

Comment: Well, no errors in LogCat but it doesn't work. It doesn't do what is supposed to do.

Comment: Please provide more details in your question. What is it *supposed* to do and what do you *want* it to do?

Comment: I want only to compare left and right buttons. So, a user needs to click one button on the left and then one on the right. But what if, user clicks one button on the left, but then instead clicking one on the right, he changes his mind about the left one and he now wants to select another one from the left. Now, there's my problem. My code compares the first one on the left and the second one he clicked on the left, and that's not good for my game. I need in that case nothing to happen.

Comment: I suggest that you write the code as you have explained so far. For now let's forget about arrays; just write a program with 4 buttons (2 "left" buttons and 2 "right" buttons). Then add a boolean flag which indicates whether or not a button on the left has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

With four buttons, `a1`, `b1`, `a2`, and `b2`, you can create two OnClickListeners: one for the `a`s and one for the `b`s. The OnClickListener should set a flag if it is the first button clicked. Then the other OnClickListener can check if the flag is set (meaning it is the second button clicked) and check if it is in a different category than the first one clicked.

Once you get that much working, you can create an array (or better yet a `List`) of buttons for each category to make the final check much easier. In fact, with a little ingenuity, you can reduce all this to a single OnClickListener since the only difference is the *data* (i.e. which buttons are in which category), not the *action*.

Comment: Can you give me some code how to do it, cause what you sad is a little advanced for me? But I can learn it from your code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @nabuko I suggest you continue writing a little bit of code at a time. You could create a OnClickListener for the `a` buttons which sets a boolean flag the first time any one of them is clicked. Then go from there. If you run into problems along the way, feel free to come back to ask more questions.

Comment: I tried with arrays. I've edited my question above, check it out, it's on the bottom of the post.